# In the Struts , How 'replacement values for message' in ActionMessage can be picked from ResourceBundle

Tags: java, struts, resourcebundle, messageformat

What I did to achieve it.

***Action File:***

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.....ApplicationResources");               
String title=rb.getString("entity.member");
messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE,new ActionMessage("message.save",title ));
```

***Application Resource :***

```
entity.member=Member
entity.Locker=Locker
message.save={0} saved successfully
```

***What I want is:***

There is a short route to replace 'replacement values for message' with hard coded word 'Member'.
like

```
messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE,new ActionMessage("message.save","Member" ));
```

But

```
1. MessageResources resources = getServlet().getInternal().getMessageResources("com....ApplicationResources")

2. ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.....ApplicationResources");

3. String title = getResources(request).getMessage(getLocale(request), "entity.member");

messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE,new ActionMessage("message.save",title ));
```

Above three are the long routes to replace 'replacement values for message' with respective language wording.

Looking for short route like I had for hard coding.

Comment: Why you dont want to give the path in `Action File` ?

Comment: because when I write "new ActionMessage("message.save","Member");" I do not need path to get "message.save" So there should be some way to get it without path or 
String title = getResources(request).getMessage(getLocale(request), "entity.member");

Answer (score 0):

Include below element in your struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
```

Extend ActionSupport to your Action Class

> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport

Use the below function wherever your need the property value

> getText(String key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MessageFormat` to format the message with arguments.

```
MessageFormat.format(rb.getString("message.save"), new Object[]{title})
```

and use it with `ActionMessage` like the Struts does when used `MessageResources`.

Comment: For Message resource again you need resource file path.

Comment: You need to load resource bundle before you can use it.